# UITabBarController Memory management problem inside UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uitabbarcontroller

I have to use a UITabBarController inside UINavigationController. Everything seems to be right, but if i log the dealloc calls of the tabs some strange thing happens.

If I don't touch eanything just the back button, all dealloc of each tabs are called.
If I switch to any other tab and than I tap the back button the dealloc of the first tab won't be called but the others will.

What can be wrong whit that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v).  Basically, a tab bar controller inside a nav controller isn't officially supported, but you can mimic the behavior by using a tab bar without a UITabBarController.