# Combining UITabBarController with UINavigationContoller

Tags: iphone, sdk, uinavigationcontroller, uitabview

I am sure this is very simple, yet I am stuck...

1. I have created an application and added UITabViewController (dragged in from the library in Interface Builder. My application has 3 different views, clicking on appropriate tab brings the different view. So far so good.
2. I want to convert one of the views to be a UINavigationController: basically a table with the option to delete rows (so UINavigationController would need to have a button "Edit" on top).

I saw many samples which would do either 1 or 2, but not both.

How would I combine it, keeping in mind that I have used provided UITabViewController and did not added UITabBar directly to the view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Interface Builder, you should be able to just drag and drop a navigation controller into your tab bar controller as a child controller.  The next tab bar item should be generated for it automatically from that.

You can also do this programatically by just creating however many UINavigationControllers you need in an array and assigning that to the uitabbarcontroller appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't like this method of combining the UINavigationController and UITabBarController since the tab bar controller must *always* be visible, which can be really confusing sometimes.

Instead, I recommend you make your own custom UITabBarController ([Tab bar controller inside a navigation controller, or sharing a navigation root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v/579087#579087)) which you add to the navigation controller. I personally don't know why Apple didn't do this; hopefully this is the standard way in 4.0 :)