# Using a navigationcontoller with a tabbar controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to make it so I have a tab bar at the bottom of my screen, and it's always there. I also want it so if I "click" into some menu in one of the tabs, it gives you the option to go back, thus a navigation controller and a tab bar controller.

I still don't really understand iOS, so the answer I found is confusing me.

This Answer: [Having a UITabBar AND a UINavigationController in an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339177/having-a-uitabbar-and-a-uinavigationcontroller-in-an-app)

So how do I implement this? I'm guessing I change this method in my App Delegate,

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[CFSDFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CFSDFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[CFSDSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CFSDSecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[CFSDFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CFSDFirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        viewController2 = [[CFSDSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CFSDSecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't need to to manually set up the nib name. You could just name them `CFSDFirstViewController~iphone.xib` and `CFSDFirstViewController~ipad.xib`. Then you can call `[[CFSDFirstViewController alloc] init]` and let iOS do the rest for you. For info see [iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW2).

About your question, you can only insert the `UINavigationController` within the `UITabBarController`. To do it wrap `viewController1` within a `UINavigationController` like the following:

```
CFSDFirstViewController viewController1 = [[CFSDFirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
```

and then use `navController` instead of `viewController1` like the folliwing

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, nil];
```

Check the code because I wrote by hand. And pay attention to memory if you use a non-ARC project.

Hope it helps.