# Add a UISegmentedControl as the titleView in a UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol, titleview

I'm trying to add a `UISegmentedControl` programmatically as the `titleView` in a `UINavigationController`. But it did not show up. Upon further investigation, I found out that the `titleView` property is ignored if the `leftBarButtonItem` is not set to `nil` according to the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html). So I set it to `nil` but still the segmented control does not show up!

Below is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    UISegmentedControl *statFilter = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Personnal", @"Department", @"Company", nil]];
    [statFilter setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = statFilter;
}
```

What should I do? What am I missing here?

Thanks.

**EDIT** :

Thanks for all the responses. However, none of them worked for me so I took a deeper look. It must be the way I have laid out my application. I probably should have mentioned that earlier. Apologies.

What I'm creating is a Storyboard app. The main controller is a `UITabBarController`. When a certain tab is clicked, I want to show a `UITableViewController`. Since you cannot display a Navigation bar in a `UITableViewController`, I found out that I must add a `UINavigationController` and implement a `UITableViewController` inside it. This is how my app basically look like,

[image]

That Dashboard View Controller is connected to a class inheriting from `UINavigationController`
 class. Maybe this is where the issue resides?

Because I just created a small test app, put a `UIViewController`, embedded in a `UINavigationController` and wrote the code I have posted in my original question above inside the `UIViewController`'s ViewDidLoad and the segmented control shows up just fine. Now I don't know how to do the same in my main app because there's no other view controllers or anything connected to the navigation controller.

Sorry if I made things even worse. Please comment if anything is unclear.

Comment: First of all you definetly can have a `UINavigationBar` combined with a `UITableViewController`. Your `UITabBarController` needs to consist of `UINavigationControllers`, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339177/having-a-uitabbar-and-a-uinavigationcontroller-in-an-app for more information about that

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to make the UISegmentedControll a UIBarButtonItem:

UPDATE:
This Code makes the SegmentedControll centered:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.title = nil;
    UISegmentedControl *statFilter = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Personnal", @"Department", @"Company", nil]];
    [statFilter setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];

    NSMutableArray *buttonArray     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    [buttonArray addObject:flexibleSpace];
    [buttonArray addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:statFilter]];
    [buttonArray addObject:flexibleSpace];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = buttonArray;
    [buttonArray release];
}
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: If I replace your four lines of code with my three lines of code, it shows up in my application...

Comment: Hold on, I think there's a small issue. I'll get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this i hope this will help you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView * navview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 160,80)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    UISegmentedControl *statFilter = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Personnal", @"Department", @"Company", nil]];
    [navview addSubview:statFilter];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navview;
}
```

Comment: the one before the last line, is it should be `[navview addsubview:statFilter];`?

Comment: more over create that statfilter in .h file so that we can any where in that view like changing images etc...