# UITabBarController + UinavigatinbarController in the middle of an application

Tags: iphone, ios4

How can I add UITabBarController + UinavigatinbarController in the middle of an iphone application.
I dont want tabbar and navigationbar in my first screen but my rest of the application require UITabBarController + UinavigatinbarController.

How can I achive that ?

What type of project do I need to create ?

Is there any example ?

Any suggestion/help.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v

Answer (score 0):

You can start with navigation controller as your main controller (with navbar hidden) and after your first screen work is finished ( I am guessing it is a login screen or welcome screen) then you can push the Tabbarcontroller using the main navigation controller.