# iPhone UITabBarController inside of UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Are there any good example of a UITabBarController inside of a UINavigationController? I have been googling it, but all I can find is the opposite (one navigation controller for each tab bar). I have two tabs and I want either to be able to control the overall navigation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tab bar controller inside a navigation controller, or sharing a navigation root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I found a similar question here:

[Tab bar controller inside a navigation controller, or sharing a navigation root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v)