# Adding tabbar controller to uiview

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I have a requirement with below steps,

```
1. Login page
2. Page2
3. Page 3 - table view
```

Now I want to display a tab barcontroller with 4 tab items on page 3. All the 4 tab items have individual view controller. Page 3 is not one of the items of tab controller, it just contains the tabcontroller so that the user can access 4 other functionalities that the app provides. I do not want to display it on the login page and page 2 so adding the tabcontroller to MainWindow is not a possibility. Can anybody please help me out with adding a tabbar controller to a uiview having uitableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this question useful: [Tab bar controller inside a navigation controller, or sharing a navigation root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v)

Alternatively, after Page2 you could swap out the entire root view controller from your window and replace it with a UITabBarController's view.  Since this won't be part of a navigation stack, you'll have to manually swap the views.