# push tabbarcontroller in iphone / multiple tabbarcontroller in iphone application

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a tabbar based project and my first tab have a navigation controller. and in my navigation controller (after push 2 views) i want to add/push one other tabbarcontroller. so please can any one suggest how i do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: After reading your post once more I think I misunderstood it! UINavigationControllers can't have a UITabBarController inside them, it only works the other way round!

If you really want to do this (really think about it!!) you could write your own implementation of a UITabBarController that is happy inside of a UINavigationController (Twitter for iPhone uses such a custom written UITabBarController)

Link: [UITabBarController insider UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v/579087#579087)

---

Just feed the tabbarcontrollers viewControllers property with an NSArray containing your UIViews.
    tabcontroller =[[UITabBarController alloc] init];

```
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navcon2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navcon3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navcon pushViewController:someuiview animated:NO];
[navcon2 pushViewController:someuiview2 animated:NO];
[navcon3 pushViewController:someuiview3 animated:NO];

[someuiview release];[someuiview2 release];[someuiview3 release];

tabcontroller.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:navcon, navcon2, navcon3, nil];
[navcon release]; [navcon2 release]; [navcon3 release];
```

someuiview*n* are subclasses of UIViewControllers (maybe UITableViewControllers for example (or whatever :))