# Different App types within one app - iOS development

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, user-friendly

I am more after an opinion about user friendliness for an app I am making.

In the process of planning for my application, I find that some parts of the app will work better with a tab bar view, others with a plain view, and other parts again with navigation view, for tables etc.

I am able to figure out how to do this, but before I get to carried away, would you as a user recommend going with one type and modify the app so it is all the same, or would you as a user feel comfortable having to switch within the app if it is set up and a comfortable change for you?

Thanks in advance for the feedback:-)
Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs and Navigation+tables aren't mutually exclusive. However I would be worried about tabs in some parts and then have the tabs missing ("plain view") for other parts.

I highly recommend you spend time re-thinking your IA (Information Architecture). If tabs make sense, can you model all your app to fit within tabs? If some functionality works as a "plain view" couldn't this view be integrated into the tab model?

As for tabs + navigation, don't forget: it's a tab that contains a navigation controller.

Hope this helps.

Comment: cheers for your input - that makes me think of some new ideas:-)

Answer (score 0):

Although you can put a tab bar in a navigation controller if you want, as described here: [Tab bar controller inside a navigation controller, or sharing a navigation root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root-v)

A lot of apps have navigation controllers insides tab bars (think like twitter apps) so users are probably used to that sort of thing - however even when you're navigating inside the tab you can still see the tab bar at the bottom (even if it changes.)