# Get Navigation Controller from Tabbar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to achieve to two things right now:

1) Have a tabbar controller inside a navigation controller

2) Depending on the selected tab, some Navigation buttons change, and I want to push some views into the navigation controller, while staying inside the currently selected tab.

Right now, I push the Navigation Controller like this:

```
GenericAddViewController *vc = [[GenericAddViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Then, inside the GenericAddViewController.m I have:

```
@interface GenericAddViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *titleTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end

@implementation GenericAddViewController

-(void)loadView
{
[super loadView];

TabOneController *tabOneController = [[TabOneController alloc]init];
tabOneController.title = @"Steps";

TabTwoController *tabTwoController = [[TabTwoController alloc]init];
tabTwoController.title = @"More Information";   

NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tabOneController, tabTwoController, nil];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self.tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1004);
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

}
```

This works. The only problem is for example in the TabOneController, I can't do any of these:

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(isDone:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:doneButton animated:NO];
```

Nor
    [self.navigationController push...]

Shouldn't be that complicated no?!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: hope this question will help u http://stackoverflow.com/q/7643452/1069290