# Unhide tabbar when a new view is pushed

Tags: iphone

I have `UITableViewController` embeded in a `UINavigationController` in my app. When a row is selected it pushes a `UITabBarController`. So far so good. The problem is that some of the tabs I  push more views but the tab bar gets hiden. I've tried setting `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO`, but it doesn't work.
I'm using XCode 4 with storyboard
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in one of my apps (though it was in iOS 4.x, using nibs not storyboard).

What I did to solve it: You want to have the root controller for each tab (the one with tabitem, etc) be a navigation controller - and when you push new views onto this navstack, they will respect the top navigation bar and bottom tab bar (they may actually display **two** navbars, so you have to be careful, but generally this is the way to go.)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root)

> *viewController*: The view controller that is pushed onto the stack. **It
>   cannot be an instance of tab bar controller**.

so pushing an instance of tab bar controller is not recommended. There's a good reference there that might accomplish the task you wanted ill just provide the link [here](http://www.wiredbob.com/2009/04/iphone-tweetie-style-navigation.html)