# UITabBar Inside UINavigationController Using Storyboard

Tags: cocoa, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbar

This is an extension of a [two year-old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root): how do you implement a UITabBar inside a UINavigationController?

Robert Conn's tutorial is outstanding and I can follow it for the most part. The trouble is, as I said, it's two to three years old. Storyboard has been introduced since then and I'd like to minimise my use of individual .xib files. Here's my effort to adapt it:

[image: UITabBar + UINavigationController]

All the frames are subclasses of UIViewController. When I run this, it works up to table cell selection. The Tabbed Book View pushed in response is completely black and is missing the tab bar. Obviously I can't post all the code, but based on those symptoms, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you been able to sort this out?

Comment: It's a project long wrapped up so I'm fuzzy on the details, but I remember the short answer was: no. I'm pretty sure I ended up using individual XIB files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if everything is all right within the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method? Within there, check if you get the right instance to the `segue.destinationViewController`. Otherwise, AFAIK, pushing a UITabBarController onto a UINavigationController might actually not be supported.