# navigation controller get me to tabbar controller in IOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Well I have read those posts and tutorials but they made me more confused:

[url 1](http://www.wiredbob.com/2009/04/iphone-tweetie-style-navigation.html)
[quest 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root?lq=1)
[quest 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136283/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-how-to-push-new-viewcontrolle)

What i want is to do this:

At the beginning my app, has a table view. when I press a row, it should take me to another view which has tabs.

What I did so far was these:

1) Created a navigation controller , and there is my tableview. When I press a row, a single view opens. In that view (with its own .xib file) I added tab bars items.

You can see pictures here:

[image: navigation controller]
[image: single view]

But now, I don't know how to make it when pressing a tab bar item, to open a new view. I am trying to embed my view in a controller but I cannot.

2) Then I tried this:
Having my navigation controller as before and I added in storyboard a tabbar controller like in that picture:
[image]

But I cannot connect them. My first view is class "SkiCenter" and code I am using is:

```
SkiCenter *myDetViewCont = [[SkiCenter alloc] initWithNibName:@"SkiCenter" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    myDetViewCont.ski_center=[centers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myDetViewCont animated:YES]; // "Pushing the controller on the screen"
    [myDetViewCont release]; // releasing controller from the memory
    myDetViewCont = nil;
```

and I get SIGBRT that says something about .nib file for "SkiCenter".

Can you suggest a sollution in either 1 or 2?

just to make it more clear:
Solution 1:
pressing the row gets me to a single uiview named skicentermain. I have added several tabbaritems but I do not know how to make them open new views.

Sollution 2:
Inserted a tabbar controller. Its first tab is SkiCenter. But when pressing the row, I get a sigbart error. it says something about the nib file of SkiCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to use storyboard you can simply put an identifier to any view controller from `attributes inspector` and then instantiate it with its id.

```
UIStoryboard * storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerID"] animated:YES];
```

Comment: I get this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x6a86ba0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'SkiCentersIds''

I gave either my TabBar Controller the name SkiCenterIds or in mu UIViewController (tab 1) that name but neither of the worked.

Comment: `UITabBarController`'s id should be SkiCentersIds.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your declaring your `*myDetViewCont` incorrectly.  You called your nib SkiCenterMain, not SkiCenter.  Also, what exactly is on SkiCenterMain?  Is that a UITabBarController?

```
//SkiCenter *myDetViewCont = [[SkiCenter alloc] initWithNibName:@"SkiCenter" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
SkiCenter *myDetViewCont = [[SkiCenter alloc] initWithNibName:@"SkiCenterMain" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: No it's called SkiCenter. Ski center is the name of UIView (tab 1) in sollution number 2. But there is no connection between navigation bar controller and tab bar controller (in sollution 2 again)

Comment: In solution 1, is the file name not SkiCenterMain.xib?  You need to create a tabBarController there, not just a UIView.  Then change the tabBarController's class to SkiCenter.

Comment: Yes but I cannot embed my view in TabBarControoller. This ooption cannot be pressed. The view opens normally so .xib is right but there it is just a single view.

Comment: Yes, you should not embed a view in the UITabBarController.  Instead, set your view as the view property of a UIViewController.  Then embed the UIViewController as one of the UITabBarController's tabs.

Comment: I did the first one, but the again UIViewController cannot be embdedded in UTabBar Controller.

Comment: You can embed a UIViewController in a tabBar.  Try this: http://www.cimgf.com/2009/06/25/uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-using-interface-builder/