# Embedding UITabBar controller inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I searched about this case but I couldn't find how to embed tab bar controller inside a navigation controller properly.

To be more specific; I created navigation controller in didFinishLauncinhWithOptions method inside the appdelagete and I am navigating through my view controllers without any problem.

I have a mainViewController with has 3 button and every button is pushing anotherView to navigation controller. In one of the views I am redirected, I want to use a tabbar.

My question is where should I create my tabbar controller in this case and is it allowed to embed tabbar controller inside navigation controller ? If not what should I do because, I really wanna embed my navigation controller from start and have navigation bar thorough out the entire program.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling some times, I managed to figured out the solution by inserting new view below the tabbar.

This thread really helped me much about the case;

[Tab bar controller inside a navigation controller, or sharing a navigation root view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root)

Cheers;