# How to get navigation based template functionality in Swift programming

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I need a navigation controller through out my project and my application has a social login initially. Once the authentication is verified user will be pushed to another view, where I display a tabbarcontroller having 2 tabs.

I don't know how to do this in Swift programming. I have embed my viewcontroller in Navigation controller, from here once the authentication is successful how do I push user to tabbar view? Tabbar should also have navigation.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root

Comment: @Dee - Did you try my solution?

Comment: No, but I understood the concept. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to replicate your idea into what I usually do in the following example.

This is how my storyboard looks like:

[image]

As you can see login/signup and Tab bar is not connected with any kind of Segue.

Here Sign in Navigation controller is setup of Initial Controller.

Assign This Navigation Controller an Storyboard ID(e.g.*LoginNavigation*):

[image: Login NavigationController]

Do the same with Tab Bar Controller, assign Storyboard ID(e.g. *HomeTabBar*)

[image: TabBarController]

Now, you just have to shuffle Root View Controller of the app between Login Nav and Tab Bar.

So if user successfully logs in, changes the application's root view to **HomeTabBar** using following code:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let home: UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeTabBar") as! UITabBarController
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = home
```

And when user logs our, again change the root view to **Login Nav**:

```
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let entryPoint:UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginNavigation")
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = entryPoint
```

The `appDelegate` is defined in my `constants.swift` file :

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```