# Segue Presently from Appdelegate to UITabBarController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, appdelegate

I want to segue from `AppDelegate` to First View of `UITabBarController`.
I assigned `StoryBoardID` of `UITabBarController` as "HomePage".

and I tried below code:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let viewController: UITabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomePage") as! UITabBarController

 let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
 rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

It works but I gave `BackBarButton` on destination view which I don't want.
I want to segue Presently.

Comment: Checkout my recent answer on: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159444/how-to-get-navigation-based-template-functionality-in-swift-programming)[How to get navigation based template functionality in Swift programming] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `viewControllers` instead of `pushViewController`

```
rootViewController.viewControllers = [viewController]
```

Instead of

```
rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```