# Remove VC after presenting VC code not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Similar to Instagram, my app shows Tabbar VC as the root VC if the user already has already logged in by checking NSUserDefault. I have the following code that deals with logout to go back to login screen

```
    if LOGIN_SCREEN_SHOWN == true {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LoginVC
            self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true) {
                //self.removeFromParentViewController()
                self.tabBarController!.removeFromParentViewController()
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
                LOGIN_SCREEN_SHOWN = true
            }
        }
```

[image: flow]

Basically LOGIN_SCREEN_SHOWN is set to true in viewWillAppear in LoginVC indicating that we have been segue'd from LoginVC.

I have deInit code with print outs in all my VC. What I am finding is that if LOGINSCREENSHOWN == TRUE,  dismissViewControllerAnimated is doing what I want to do and calling all the deInit code in all my VC printing out

```
NavVC Deinit Successfully
NavVC Deinit Successfully
NavVC Deinit Successfully
NavVC Deinit Successfully

VC1 Deinit Successfully
VC2 Deinit Successfully
VC3 Deinit Successfully
VC4 Deinit Successfully
```

However, the code under "else" where I present Login VC and attempt to remove VC from after LoginVC is presented does not give me the print out indicating that the code is not doing what I'd like it to do. Could someone please point me to the right direction

----UPDATE----

This is the final code that works from Ketan Parmar. I have modified the transition type and duration to mimic dismissViewControllerAnimated animation

```
        if LOGIN_SCREEN_SHOWN == true {
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        } else {
            // Custom transition
            let transition : CATransition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.35
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom

            let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LoginVC
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
            appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
            LOGIN_SCREEN_SHOWN = true
        }
```

Comment: In which method you are implementing             self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) ?

Comment: Somewhat similar query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159444/how-to-get-navigation-based-template-functionality-in-swift-programming/39159793#39159793

Comment: dissmissViewControllerAnimated is implemented in VC4 with a logoutBtn

Comment: @Mr.UB, this is un-related to that question you linked

Comment: hmm..1 query: why do you want to use this line of code: `self.tabBarController!.removeFromParentViewController()`?

Comment: No specific reason really. I was just trying things to see if any code can successfully de-initalise the VCs that I am leaving behind

Comment: finally you trying to do if user logged in so he/she directed to `tabView` if not he will be directed to loginView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should manage this in `appdeledate` something like first check that does your user is logged in(userdefaults or whatever)? If yes then do nothing because you have set your `tabBarVC` as initial viewcontroller in `storyboard`. Now, if no that means you want to show `loginViewController` then instantiate `loginViewController` and set it as rootviewcontroller of window. and after successfully login show `tabbarVC` by segue or by `instantiate` it. that't it.

**Update :**

```
    let loginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginVC") as! LoginVC
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginVC
```

That much code only require to set `loginVC` as rootVC.

**Update 2:**

for animation add below code snippet before setting `rootVC`,

```
 let transition : CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.2
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I am doing already. But the question mentioned above is that if the user has tabBarVC as the rootVC and wants to go back to loginVC because he wants to log out, the code does not cause the existing VCs to deinit

Comment: Could you please take a look at my code and provide and example. Because as you can see in my else section, I did try and set loginvc as root vc and it didnt work. Cheers

Comment: That works! Thanks champ. One question, there is no animation doing it this way as the login screen just appears instantly. How would I be able to do it so it has the animation of popping view controller or dismissing view controller?

Comment: You kind sir seems very passionated! Thanks for providing such good answer so quickly. I have updated the question with your answer