# How to add tab bar controller instead of a protected page in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, xcode7

I have a protected page embedded in Navigation Controller. If a user is logged in, they can access the protected page or else the login view appears.

As of now, the protected page has a segue to login view and it works fine.

Now, on the protected page I need to add tabs. So I want to use tab bar controller. I am unable to figure out how to give segue to login view. Should I give it from the tab bar controller or from the first item view of tab bar controller.

As I am new to Xcode and swift, I am bit confused on how to build my application. Please help

Comment: This can be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159444/how-to-get-navigation-based-template-functionality-in-swift-programming/39159793#39159793

Comment: The solution in the above thread worked for me