# Why UITabBarViewController does not display the tab bar?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

This looks like just a simple problem, but I can't find what's wrong.

I have a `UINavigationController` pointing to a `UIViewController` A, pointing to a `UITabBarController`. The `UITabBarController` handles two `UIViewControllers` B & C, so I can see two tab bar item on the `UITabBarController`.

When the app run, the `UIViewController` A is shown. Then after tapping on a button, the `UIViewController` B is shown (which is supposedly within the `UITabBarController`). But the tab bar is not shown. Only the `UIViewController` B and navigation bar.

Can someone help why this is happening?

EDIT: some screenshots:

[image: Screenshot of the UITabBarViewController]

[image: The UITabBarViewController is assigned properly to the flow]

Comment: How are you moving from A to B, using Normal button or Tab Bar button?

Comment: Share screenshot or some code for better understanding.

Comment: @Mr.UB just using a simple login `UIButton`.

Comment: @Arasuvel I would like to, but I'm working with tablet sized simulated metrics, so I can only give limited screenshot which might be more confusing. But I'll try.

Comment: Check my popular post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159444/how-to-get-navigation-based-template-functionality-in-swift-programming/39159793#39159793

Comment: @Mr.UB in my case, the `UITabBarViewController` has attached properly into the flow. See my second screenshot. To the left is the login screen (`UIViewController` A). To the right is the `UIViewController` B, which is the first default view of the `UITabBarViewController`. To the bottom (not seen) is the `UIViewController` C, which is part of the managed `UIViewController` along with the B (see my first screenshot).

Comment: I know, but apple clearly suggests that do not embed Tab Bar Controller into the Navigation Controller, it is against their app architecture design. They say that the Tab Bar Controller should be root view.

Comment: @Mr.UB It's not. The problem is, I have been able to pull this off before in the past, so I know this is possible. But I never encounter such problem like this. In the past, it works perfectly like expected. So I don't know what's wrong in this case.

Comment: Please post image of full story board with A view controller too.

Comment: @Mr.UB I got the problem. There's a segue from the VC A to the UITabBarViewController, BUT when I click on the Login button, it's actually running a `touchUpInside` IBAction code that's directly fetch the VC B from the storyboard and push it, not run the segue at all. Thank you for your patience in trying to understand the problem.