# How to segue from a nav controller to tab controller and make it root view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

Hello i have a login screen and registration screen in a nav controller for when a user signs in or wants to sign up in an application. I also created a Tab controller that displays the home page screen. After the user signs in or signs up i want to be able to segue to the tab controller and make this the root view controller and thus the user cannot go back to the sign in or register page. Please how can this be accomplished?

Below is few lines of code when the user signs in

```
if statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)
                    let result = json as? [String: AnyObject]
                    guard let token = result!["token"], let firstname = result!["user"]!["firstname"]! else {
                        print("Error: \(error?.debugDescription)")
                        return
                    }

                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(token, forKey: "token")
                //code to segue to the tab controller from the nav controller (login screen)
                self.getHome()

                }
                catch {
                    print("Error receiving data")
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()



    func getHome() {
     let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tableController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabController") as? UITableViewController

        let appledDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appledDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tableController
 }
```

in my AppDelegate.swift in  file i check to see if there is a token if not calls the Login page or show home page:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let obj = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("token")

    if obj == nil {

    let welcomeHomeController:UIViewController = WelcomeHomeController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    welcomeHomeController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let navController:UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeHomeController)

    //create window
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    self.window?.rootViewController = navController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

    }
```

Comment: This post might help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159444/how-to-get-navigation-based-template-functionality-in-swift-programming/39159793#39159793

Answer (score 0):

```
func getHome() {
 let storyboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let navController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabController") as? UINavigationController //be sure to set the "tabController" in the navigationController and not in the tabcontroller

    let next = navController.topViewController as! YourTabRootViewController
    self.navigationController.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```