# A TabBarViewController cannot be presented as a child. Consider using Root instead

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

On the start of my iOS application (that I am building with Xamarin and MvvmCross), I want to immediately change `UIViewController` to a `UITabBarViewController`. My code:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public void Initialization()
    {
        ShowViewModel<TabLayoutViewModel>(); // Breaks here
    }
}

public class MainViewController : BaseViewController<MainViewModel>
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        this.ViewModel.Initialization();
    }
}

public class TabLayoutViewController : MvxTabBarViewController<TabLayoutViewModel>
{
}
```

On the line `ShowViewModel<TabLayoutViewModel>()` it throws an exception:

> A TabBarViewController cannot be presented as a child. Consider using
>   Root instead

I just want to push this controller on top of the stack. I know this is legal in plain iOS so there should be a way to do it with MvvmCross?

Comment: If it is not possible it is a bug. As you say yourself, it should be possible to push a TabBarViewController on top of the stack. If you can't find a way to do it. Please report a bug in the MvvmCross GitHub issues.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Since MvvmCross 5.0.4 it is now possible to show a TabBarController as a child. Just mark your TabBarController with [MvxChildPresentation].

See this [PR](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/1977) to the source code..

---

Original answer:

A `TabBarController` is not meant to be presented inside a UINavigationController. What you can do is to change the root ViewController of your Window. To do so, you can add the `MvxRootPresentation` attribute above the TabLayoutViewController class.

If you do need to show tabs inside a UINavigationController, you might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root) relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do just that last week.

What I do to quickly resolve this is simple:

1) Create a custom presenter that inherits from MvxIosViewPresenter (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/iOS/iOS/Views/Presenters/MvxIosViewPresenter.cs).

2) Override the ShowChildViewController method, using the original as model and comment these two lines:

```
if (viewController is IMvxTabBarViewController)
    throw new MvxException("A TabBarViewController cannot be presented as a child. Consider using Root instead");
```

3) Override the CreatePresenter method in Setup.cs:

```
protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
{
    return new CustomTabChildMvxIosViewPresenter(ApplicationDelegate, Window);
}
```

Comment: This is the correct direction, actually in latest MvvmCross version, the limitation is already removed.